# Joining 2 dataframes pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Pyspark.
I have data like this in 2 tables as below. I am using data frames.

**Table1:**

| Id | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | £100 | 01/04/2021 |
| 1 | £50 | 08/04/2021 |
| 2 | £60 | 02/04/2021 |
| 2 | £20 | 06/05/2021 |

**Table2:**

| Id | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | 01/04/2021 |
| 1 | S2 | 05/04/2021 |
| 1 | S3 | 10/04/2021 |
| 2 | S1 | 02/04/2021 |
| 2 | S2 | 10/04/2021 |

I need to join those 2 data frames above to produce output like this as below.

For every record in table 1, we need to get the record from table 2 valid as of that `Date` and vice versa. For e.g, `table1` has `£50` for `Id=1` on `08/04/2021` but table 2 has a record for `Id=1` on `05/04/2021` where status changed to `S2`. So, for `08/04/2021` the status is `S2`. That's what I am not sure how to give in the join condition to get this output

What's the efficient way of achieving this?

**Expected Output:**

| Id | Status | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | 01/04/2021 | £100 |
| 1 | S2 | 05/04/2021 | £100 |
| 1 | S2 | 08/04/2021 | £50 |
| 1 | S3 | 10/04/2021 | £50 |
| 2 | S1 | 02/04/2021 | £60 |
| 2 | S2 | 10/04/2021 | £60 |
| 2 | S2 | 06/05/2021 | £20 |

Comment: Please [don't post dataframe data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), use text format. Also, what is the join condition?

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I have removed the images and used table format. For every record in table 1, we need to get the record from table 2 valid as of that date and vice versa. For e.g, table1 has £50 for id1 on 08/04/2021 but table 2 has a record for id 1 on 05/04/2021 where status changed to S2. So, for 08/04/2021 the status is S2.  That's what I am not sure how to give in the join condition to get this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full join on `Id` and `Date` then [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html) window function to get the values of `Status` and `Amount` from the precedent closest `Date` row:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("Id").orderBy(F.to_date("Date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))

joined_df = df1.join(df2, ["Id", "Date"], "full").withColumn(
    "Status",
    F.coalesce(F.col("Status"), F.lag("Status").over(w))
).withColumn(
    "Amount",
    F.coalesce(F.col("Amount"), F.lag("Amount").over(w))
)

joined_df.show()
#+---+----------+------+------+
#| Id|      Date|Amount|Status|
#+---+----------+------+------+
#|  1|01/04/2021|  £100|    S1|
#|  1|05/04/2021|  £100|    S2|
#|  1|08/04/2021|   £50|    S2|
#|  1|10/04/2021|   £50|    S3|
#|  2|02/04/2021|   £60|    S1|
#|  2|10/04/2021|   £60|    S2|
#|  2|06/05/2021|   £20|    S2|
#+---+----------+------+------+
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I have tried your solution and it worked perfectly fine. The only change i have done is I have ordered by id and date